# error: no matching member function for call to 'push'

Tags: c++, tree, stack

```
Line 30: Char 11: error: no matching member function for call to 'push'
       s1.push(root);
       ~~~^~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_stack.h:233:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Node *' to 'const std::stack<TreeNode *, std::deque<TreeNode *, std::allocator<TreeNode *>>>::value_type' (aka 'TreeNode *const') for 1st argument
      push(const value_type& __x)
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_stack.h:238:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Node *' to 'std::stack<TreeNode *, std::deque<TreeNode *, std::allocator<TreeNode *>>>::value_type' (aka 'TreeNode *') for 1st argument
      push(value_type&& __x)
      ^
```

````
public:
   vector<int> postorder(Node* root) {
       vector<int> v;
        if(root==NULL){
            return v;
        }
         stack<TreeNode *> s1;
       stack<TreeNode *> s2;
       s1.push(root);
       while(!s1.empty()){
           TreeNode* f=s1.top();
           s1.pop();
           s2.push(f);
           
           for(int i=0;i<f->children.size();i++){
               if(f->children[i]){
                   s1.push(f->children[i]);
               }
           }
           
           
       }
       while(!s2.empty()){
           v.push_back(s2.top()->val);
           s2.pop()
       }
       return v;
   }
};```
````

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. What is `TreeNode`? What is the relation between `Node*` (the type of `root`) and `TreeNode*` (what the stack contains)?

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Is it a typo or function is taking `Node *` type of pointer and stack is for `TreeNode *` type

Answer (score 2):

`s1` is of type `stack<TreeNode *>`, which means that it can only `push` values of `TreeNode *` type.

But `root` is of type `Node*` , which is different than `TreeNode *`.

Even if these types are similar ( and maybe convertible), because the function's argument is not recognized as `TreeNode *` type, the function is not recognized as a whole, hence the error!

If you pay attention to the error message it is saying that the argument of the `push` function should either be `const value_type&` or `value_type&&`. which means either `const TreeNode *&` or `TreeNode *&&`!

`root` is of none of those types!